# Mapping MMIO region write-back does not work

Tags: linux, caching, x86, fpga, pci-e

I want all read & write requests to a PCIe device to be cached by CPU caches. However, it does not work as I expected.

These are my assumptions on write-back MMIO regions.

1. Writes to the PCIe device happen only on cache write-back.
2. The size of TLP payloads is cache block size (64B).

However, captured TLPs do not follow my assumptions.

1. Writes to the PCIe device happen on every write to the MMIO region.
2. The size of TLP payloads is 1B.

I write 8-byte of `0xff` to the MMIO region with the following user space program & device driver.

**Part of User Program**

```
struct pcie_ioctl ioctl_control;
ioctl_control.bar_select = BAR_ID;
ioctl_control.num_bytes_to_write = atoi(argv[1]);
if (ioctl(fd, IOCTL_WRITE_0xFF, &ioctl_control) < 0) {
    printf("ioctl failed\n");
}
```

**Part of Device Driver**

```
case IOCTL_WRITE_0xFF:
{
    int i;
    char *buff;
    struct pci_cdev_struct *pci_cdev = pci_get_drvdata(fpga_pcie_dev.pci_device);
    copy_from_user(&ioctl_control, (void __user *)arg, sizeof(ioctl_control));
    buff = kmalloc(sizeof(char) * ioctl_control.num_bytes_to_write, GFP_KERNEL);
    for (i = 0; i < ioctl_control.num_bytes_to_write; i++) {
        buff[i] = 0xff;
    }
    memcpy(pci_cdev->bar[ioctl_control.bar_select], buff, ioctl_control.num_bytes_to_write);
    kfree(buff);
    break;
}
```

I modified MTRRs to make the corresponding MMIO region write-back. The MMIO region starts from 0x0c7300000, and the length is 0x100000 (1MB). Followings are `cat /proc/mtrr` results for different policies. Please note that I made each region exclusive.

**Uncacheable**

```
reg00: base=0x080000000 ( 2048MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: uncachable
reg01: base=0x380000000000 (58720256MB), size=524288MB, count=1: uncachable
reg02: base=0x0c0000000 ( 3072MB), size=   64MB, count=1: uncachable
reg03: base=0x0c4000000 ( 3136MB), size=   32MB, count=1: uncachable
reg04: base=0x0c6000000 ( 3168MB), size=   16MB, count=1: uncachable
reg05: base=0x0c7000000 ( 3184MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg06: base=0x0c7100000 ( 3185MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg07: base=0x0c7200000 ( 3186MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg08: base=0x0c7300000 ( 3187MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg09: base=0x0c7400000 ( 3188MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
```

**Write-combining**

```
reg00: base=0x080000000 ( 2048MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: uncachable
reg01: base=0x380000000000 (58720256MB), size=524288MB, count=1: uncachable
reg02: base=0x0c0000000 ( 3072MB), size=   64MB, count=1: uncachable
reg03: base=0x0c4000000 ( 3136MB), size=   32MB, count=1: uncachable
reg04: base=0x0c6000000 ( 3168MB), size=   16MB, count=1: uncachable
reg05: base=0x0c7000000 ( 3184MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg06: base=0x0c7100000 ( 3185MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg07: base=0x0c7200000 ( 3186MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg08: base=0x0c7300000 ( 3187MB), size=    1MB, count=1: write-combining
reg09: base=0x0c7400000 ( 3188MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
```

**Write-back**

```
reg00: base=0x080000000 ( 2048MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: uncachable
reg01: base=0x380000000000 (58720256MB), size=524288MB, count=1: uncachable
reg02: base=0x0c0000000 ( 3072MB), size=   64MB, count=1: uncachable
reg03: base=0x0c4000000 ( 3136MB), size=   32MB, count=1: uncachable
reg04: base=0x0c6000000 ( 3168MB), size=   16MB, count=1: uncachable
reg05: base=0x0c7000000 ( 3184MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg06: base=0x0c7100000 ( 3185MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg07: base=0x0c7200000 ( 3186MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg08: base=0x0c7300000 ( 3187MB), size=    1MB, count=1: write-back
reg09: base=0x0c7400000 ( 3188MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
```

Followings are waveform captures for 8B write with different policies. I have used integrated logic analyzer (ILA) to capture these waveform. Please watch `pcie_endpoint_litepcietlpdepacketizer_tlp_req_payload_dat` when `pcie_endpoint_litepcietlpdepacketizer_tlp_req_valid` is set. You can count the number of packets by counting `pcie_endpoint_litepcietlpdepacketizer_tlp_req_valid` in these waveform example.

1. **Uncacheable**: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubxfn.png) ->  correct, 1B x 8 packets
2. **Write-combining**: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wheZf.png) ->  correct, 8B x 1 packet
3. **Write-back**: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCeIc.png) ->  unexpected, 1B x 8 packets

System configuration is like below.

- **CPU**: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
- **OS**: Linux kernel 4.15.0-38
- **PCIe Device**: Xilinx FPGA KC705 programmed with [litepcie](https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litepcie)

**Related Links**

1. [Generating a 64-byte read PCIe TLP from an x86 CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918804/generating-a-64-byte-read-pcie-tlp-from-an-x86-cpu)
2. [How to Implement a 64B PCIe* Burst Transfer on Intel® Architecture](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/pcie-burst-transfer-paper.pdf)
3. [Write Combining Buffer Out of Order Writes and PCIe](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/711304)
4. [Do Ryzen support write-back caching for Memory Mapped IO (through PCIe interface)?](https://community.amd.com/thread/229989)
5. [MTRR (Memory Type Range Register) control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/mtrr.txt)
6. [PATting Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v2-pages-135-144.pdf)
7. [Down to the TLP: How PCI express devices talk (Part I)](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1)

Comment: Is it possible that something else (like PAT) is overriding the MTRR setting and making it actually be UC instead of WB?  An BTW, the single-byte transactions might be from `mempcy` being implemented as `rep movsb` inside the kernel (because your CPU is new enough for ERMSB which makes `rep movsb` fairly good.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, Peter. I could find a conflict in PAT. The region is set as `uncached-minus` in PAT. I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it seems that mapping MMIO region write-back does not work by design.

Please upload an answer if anyone finds that it is possible.

I came to find John McCalpin's articles and answers. First, mapping MMIO region write-back is not possible. Second, workaround is possible on some processors.

1. **Mapping MMIO region write-back is not possible**

   [Quote from this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/628155)

   > FYI: The WB type will not work with memory-mapped IO.   You can
   >   program the bits to set up the mapping as WB, but the system will
   >   crash as soon as it gets a transaction that it does not know how to
   >   handle.  It is theoretically possible to use WP or WT to get cached
   >   reads from MMIO, but coherence has to be handled in software.

   [Quote from this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/393070)

   > Only when I set both PAT and MTRR to WB does the kernel crash
2. **Workaround is possible on some processors**

   [Notes on Cached Access to Memory-Mapped IO Regions, John McCalpin](https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2013/05/29/notes-on-cached-access-to-memory-mapped-io-regions/)

   > There is one set of mappings that can be made to work on at least some
   >   x86-64 processors, and it is based on mapping the MMIO space *twice*.
   >   Map the MMIO range with a set of attributes that allow write-combining
   >   stores (but only uncached reads). Map the MMIO range a second time
   >   with a set of attributes that allow cache-line reads (but only
   >   uncached, non-write-combined stores).

Comment: I wonder if anything changes with Skylake-SP where 64-byte stores are possible to UC MMIO regions with a single AVX512 instruction.  But probably cache eviction is still different from a `movntps [rdi], zmm0`, or `movaps` on a UC memory region.