# Confused about difference between Intel Optane's Memory Drive Technology (IMDT) and DCPMM memory mode

Tags: memory, storage, intel, persistent-memory

I am confused about difference between IMDT and Intel DCPMM's memory mode.
I understood that both technology use DRAM as an extra L4 Cache, and Intel DCPMM's memory mode makes DRAM non-addressable (which means system memory is only shown as sum of DCPMMs' capacity). I referred link below.

https://venturebeat.com/2019/12/09/optane-essentials-part-2-memory-modes-and-optimal-workloads/

So my question is, does IMDT also make system DRAM non-addressable? Moreover, when I use IMDT, does system DRAM shown as system memory count?

Thanks.

Comment: L4 cache of what?  Of the DC PM?  Possibly related: [Confused about Intel Optane DC SSD usage as extra RAM with IMDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58203102) - IMDT is just a fancy name for using an Optane SSD as swap space, it seems.  It doesn't even have to be DC PM.

Comment: I understood IMDT is used with Optane SSDs. My question is, in case of using Optane SSD with IMDT, is DRAM shown as an addressable space?