# Use AVX-AVX2 instructions in an AVX512 function

Tags: assembly, simd, avx, avx512

For example, we have a CPU with AVX512bw support.
Now i want to run 3 types of string-length SIMD functions on this CPU.

- The first function takes 16 bytes (AVX) of a string and search its characters for the null-terminator, and this continues until a null-terminator achieved.
- The second function takes 32 bytes (AVX2) of a string and search its characters for the null-terminator, and this continues until a null-terminator achieved.
- The third function takes 64 bytes (AVX512bw) of a string and search its characters for the null-terminator, and this continues until a null-terminator achieved.

But I can't understand that for AVX512 CPU, the whole 3 functions must uses AVX512 instructions or just use their SIMD instructions ?
For example, for the first function, I have to use `vmovdqa` or `vmovdqa16` !!! ???
Or for the second function, I have to use `vmovdqa` or `vmovdqa32` !!! ???

Why there are such `vmovdqa16`, `vmovdqa32` and ... instructions when we just can use their `AVX` or `AVX2` instructions ??!!

Is it possible to use AVX, AVX2 instructions in a AVX512 function ?? Or we must use the AVX512 version of those instructions ?

Comment: *Why there are such vmovdqa16, vmovdqa32 and ... instructions when we just can use their AVX or AVX2 instructions ??!!* - So you can do per-element masking, and so you can access X/YMM16-31.  If you don't want that, use `vmovdqa` for 16 or 32-byte vectors.  There's zero problem using shorter VEX encodings for 16 or 32-byte operand-size and then using AVX-512 instructions with that same vector width (AVX-512VL) or 512-bit on load results from `vmovdqa` or `vmovdqu`.  You can see this if you compile code with intrinsics using a mix of vector widths.

Comment: `vmovdqa16` -- does this exist?

Comment: @harold: Actually no, for 8 and 16-bit element size, only alignment-not-required `vmovdqu8/16` exist.  There are `vmovdqa32/64`, though.

Comment: Related: [What is the penalty of mixing EVEX and VEX encoded scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46080327) - no penalty.  And it mentions an example like AVX1 `vpxor xmm0,xmm0,xmm0` being the most efficient way to zero a ZMM register.

Comment: AVX-512 CPUs can run SSE and AVX1 / AVX2 instructions.  Otherwise they couldn't run existing binaries.  It should be obvious that the first 2 cases can use AVX `vmovdqa` exactly like previous CPUs; backwards compatibility has historically been x86's main selling point.

Comment: Near duplicate: [What is the difference between \_mm512\_load\_epi32 and \_mm512\_load\_si512?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53905757) explains the existence of `vmovdqa32` and `vmovdqa64` (masking), as well as the naming of intrinsics for them.  Also semi-related, [How to load a avx-512 zmm register from a ioremap() address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60699914) showing that you need `vmovdqa32` (or 64) to load ZMM registers.  (But doesn't address the question of using `vmovdqa ymm` on CPUs with AVX-512 support).